# Issues while using swift code in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, language-interoperability

I am very new to iOS who is trying to use swift in objective-c. I created a swift class in the objective-c project and i am able to call that class from an objective-c view controller.

The problem is if i make any changes in the swift code, it doesn't seem to be available immediately for objective-c class to access. Each time i change something in the swift class, i will have to build the project and only then it seems to be available in objective-c.

Is there a configuration that i am missing or it is expected to work this way by design?

Comment: Is live issues turned on? I think it compiles code automatically after you're done typing. To check, go to Xcode Settings -> General -> Show live issues (make sure it's on).

Comment: Yup that is switched on.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this explanation from apple. Read the sub-heading "Importing Swift into Objective-C". The generation of header files might be the explanation for your issue.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122.

Comment: Thats the first thing i did. No luck there as well.